# Rake: warning: string literal in condition

Tags: ruby, rake

I have the following line of code and every time I run any `rake` command I get the warning.

Is there a way to fix this so that it doesn't warn me?

`not(system %Q{git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git vim/bundle/vundle}) && 'Could not clone Vundle'`

Edit:

Here is the link to the Rakefile: https://github.com/deiga/dotfiles/blob/master/Rakefile#L244

It points to the line I highlighted in the question.
I invoke rake by simply typing `rake` or `rake update` on the cli.

Comment: please provide more information: how do you invoke rake? how does the error exactly look like? how does the code of your rake task look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get this warning when you evaluate a plain string like after you `&&` because it will ALWAYS be true!

```
irb(main):003:0> puts "blupp" if "bla"
(irb):3: warning: string literal in condition
blupp
=> nil
```

Comment: I do know why I get the warning, I'm looking for a way to either fix the code or the rake call to not issue those warnings

Comment: What do you mean? I want my rake tasks to output errors if the system commands go amiss

Comment: but there is nothing printed! no puts or whatever, its just a string!